# How to write a response directly in http-kit?

Tags: clojure, http-kit

how do I write a response directly in http-kit? I'm building a tunneling proxy and need the very first response to be exactly `"HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n",` but it seems http-kit renders that as a *body*, even if I do something like `{:status "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established"}`

Comment: Please provide the code for your problem and how it fails

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure http-kit to use a proxy?

Here's an example from their test-suite:

```
@(http/get "https://127.0.0.1:9898/get"
                                           {:proxy-url "http://127.0.0.1:4348"})
```